# Convert a list into an arranged dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have my list which is stored in `info` and it contains -

`['Stephanie Ramirez', 'Greater Tampa Bay Area', '500+ connections', 'Jacobs', 'Technical Recruiter', '2019 – Present', '2 yrs']`

how i wanted it to be in a dataframe so that I can export it to an excel file later like -

| name | location | connection | company | position | duration | tenure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stephanie Ramirez | Greater Tampa Bay Area | 500+ connections | Jacobs | Technical Recruiter | 2019 – Present | 2 yrs |

here's my code where it extracts data and appends in `info`

```py
name_div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'flex-1 mr5'})
name_loc = name_div.find_all('ul')
name = name_loc[0].find('li').get_text().strip()
loc = name_loc[1].find('li').get_text().strip()
connection = name_loc[1].find_all('li')
connection = connection[1].get_text().strip()
info = []
info.append(name)
info.append(loc)
info.append(connection)
info
```

`['Stephanie Ramirez', 'Greater Tampa Bay Area', '500+ connections']`

```py
#experience setion
exp_section = soup.find('section', {'id': 'experience-section'})
exp_section = exp_section.find('ul')
div_tag = exp_section.find('div')
a_tag = div_tag.find('a')
job_title = a_tag.find('h3').get_text().strip()
company_name = a_tag.find_all('p')[1].get_text().strip()
joining_date = a_tag.find_all('h4')[0].find_all('span')[1].get_text().strip()
exp = a_tag.find_all('h4')[1].find_all('span')[1].get_text().strip()
info.append(company_name)
info.append(job_title)
info.append(joining_date)
info.append(exp)
info
```

`['Stephanie Ramirez', 'Greater Tampa Bay Area', '500+ connections', 'Jacobs', 'Technical Recruiter', '2019 – Present', '2 yrs']`

please help me to get my desired OP in a dataframe.
Thanks in advance!!

just asking, the way I have posted the question is it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
In [131]: import pandas as pd

In [132]: info = ['Stephanie Ramirez', 'Greater Tampa Bay Area', '500+ connections', 'Jacobs', 'Technical Recruiter', '2019 – Present', '2 yrs']

In [137]: df = pd.DataFrame(info).T

In [139]: df.columns = ['name', 'location', 'connection', 'company', 'position', 'duration', 'tenure']

In [140]: df
Out[140]: 
                name                location        connection company             position        duration tenure
0  Stephanie Ramirez  Greater Tampa Bay Area  500+ connections  Jacobs  Technical Recruiter  2019 – Present  2 yrs
```

Comment: sir thanks a lot it worked and I  get my my desired OP. Sir, I have another querie related to this post, need to solve will it be ok to ask here in the comment?..will you allow it?

Comment: @Yes_I_needHelp Its better to post a new question.

Comment: I just need to ask that as I am extracting data from a profile, so the code throws an error where the details are not filled, for eg - position is not mentioned in that case it gives error, Sir how to solve this?

Comment: I would need more info for this.

Comment: Sir, if you allow, may I share the WETRANSFER link?..I will post my code and the link for the profile where the error comes?

Comment: here's the code I have uploaded in wetransfer - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c507a3d20a16e536bb8bd7aae9fd8e6d20210322074309/c32af9

Comment: Sir please check